# Symfony Upload: Could not Move File

Tags: symfony, file-upload, doctrine

I have implemented symfony form for file upload. The form type is like below

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('file', 'file', array(
        'required' => false,
        'label' => 'Upload Photo',
        'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label')

    ));  
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => '<path to entity>'
        ));
}
```

The Entity is like below

```
//start upload config
/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="5M")
 */
private $file;

/**
 * @var string $photo
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $photo;


/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    //handle upload file 
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $filename    = $this->getUsername();
        // var_dump($filename);
        $this->photo = $filename.'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
    }        
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    //handle upload file gambar
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    } else {
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->photo);
        unset($this->file);
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    //handle upload file gambar
    if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}

/**
 * Image upload
 */
public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->photo ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->photo;
}

/**
 * Image upload
 */
public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->photo ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->photo;
}

/**
 * Image upload
 */
protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

/**
 * Image upload
 */
protected function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'foto';
}
```

And inside the action is like below

```
$entityItem->upload();
$this->em()->persist($entityItem);
$this->em()->flush();
```

I try to submit the form data, then i get error like below

```
Could not move the file "/tmp/phpS3TVed" to 
"<path to my entity folder>/../../../../web/foto" 
(move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpS3TVed' to 
'path to my entity folder>/../../../../web/foto')
```

what is possible cause of this error and how can i get rid of it? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Sometimes i tried removing the call of upload(). Yet the method became never being called at all.

Comment: Have you checked permissions ? (ie the user that the HTTP server runs under needs permissions to write to that directory)

Comment: even i have changed the web/foto folder to 777..

Comment: the owner is www-data

Comment: Check real path of the upload folder and ensure it is corrent. Execute `echo realpath($this->getUploadRootDir()); exit;`

Comment: yes, the real path is correct.

Comment: Take a look at comments on this page http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php You could find the answer there.

Comment: check the form encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Solved.

It doesn't need to remove the call of upload(). Even i should add call preUpload() too to get it working.

Comment: Can you re-phrase that?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, it is a misunderstanding: you have to persist the entity File (manually in the controller or by cascading) in order to launch preUpload (which is triggered by event prePersist).